# select2: swapping between text and value in multiple select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

For some prototyping reasons I am tweaking the select2 plugin, particularly the multiple selection. I need to do two things:

1. `<option value="VAL123">This is value 123</option>` The options dropdown should show option's text *This is the value 123* (default behaviour), but when selected, the "select2-search-choice" should display the selected value *VAL123*, not the text.
2. If the selection is greater than 1, I need to show a custom message text, like *Multiple options selected*, not the options themselves. Ideally, the selection would also avoid deleting the selected option(s) from the dropdown.

I know it seems like breaking the logic of the plugin and is probably not doable with the provided API. Any hardcore Select2 experts here to help me tweak the source code on any of these issues?

Thanks!

UPDATE: The selected options are not deleted from the list, they are just marked with the ".select2-selected" class, which can be edited in select2.css to show them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the plug in as is and use the formatSelection option and give a function such as

```
   formatSelection: function(item) {
        return item.id
    }
```

here's a fiddle forked from someone's multiselect select2 fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ba98G/